# Jquery fadein when innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 divs, #left and #right, and with jquery I innerHTML by clicking a button some content, the problem is that it doesnt fadeIn. It is placing the content right but doesnt fadein This is what I have tried:

```
   $('#normal').click(function () {

            var left =  " content to the left ";
            var right= "content to the right"

            $('#left').html(left).fadeIn();
            $('#right').html(right).fadeIn();
});
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501398/delay-changing-innerhtml-text-using-jquery) but it didn't work on my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you placed your `click` event on DOM ready ?

Comment: edit: I think you must fadeOut the other div and then fadeIn the one was clicked.

Comment: Yes, the click event is on DOM ready.
My #normal div is 'display:none' at the start but it shows up when I click other div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#left` and `#right` should be hidden before calling `fadeIn()`.

```
#left, #right {
    display:none
}
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/yosalosi/1/edit

Comment: Thank you. I forgot it wasn't display:none the the parent div was.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't set the `display` to `none` for the divs

```
<div id="left" style="display:none;">hello
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezqv5/)

Comment: Working now, thanks!! I forgot it wasn't display:none the the parent div was.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
      $('#normal').click(function () 
      {

        var left =  " content to the left ";
        var right= "content to the right"
        $('#left,#right').hide()
        $('#left').html(left).fadeIn();
        $('#right').html(right).fadeIn();
     });
```

or

```
    #left,#right
    {
       display:none;
    }

      $('#normal').click(function () 
      {

        var left =  " content to the left ";
        var right= "content to the right"
        $('#left').html(left).fadeIn();
        $('#right').html(right).fadeIn();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this trick works:

$('#normal').click(function () {

```
        var left =  " content to the left ";
        var right= "content to the right"

        $('#left').hide().fadeIn(function(){ $(this).html(left); });
        $('#right').hide().fadeIn(function(){ $(this).html(right); });
```

});

There are two things here. First if your divs are already visible then you won't get that fadeIn effect. And secondly, you could use complete callback event of the faceIn function to add contents instead of adding contents upfront.